# Spark 3.0 streaming metrics in Prometheus

Tags: apache-spark, prometheus, spark-structured-streaming, spark3

I'm running a Spark 3.0 application (Spark Structured Streaming) on Kubernetes and I'm trying to use the new native Prometheus metric sink.  I'm able to make it work and get all the metrics described [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#executor-metrics).

However, the metrics I really need are the ones provided upon enabling the following config: spark.sql.streaming.metricsEnabled, as proposed in [this Spark Summit presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/dongjoon/native-support-of-prometheus-monitoring-in-apache-spark-3?slide=32).  Now, even with that config set to "true", I can't see any streaming metrics under `/metrics/executors/prometheus` as advertised.  One thing to note is that I can see them under `metrics/json`, therefore, we know that the configuration was properly applied.

Why aren't streaming metrics sent to the Prometheus sink?  Do I need to add some additional configuration? Is that not supported yet?

Comment: Hey Jeremie, did you get this to work?

Comment: Hey @AIJoris, see the answer below!  Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite a bit of investigation, I was able to make it work.  In short, the Spark job k8s definition file needed one additional line, to tell spark where to find the `metrics.propreties` config file.

Make sure to add the following line under `sparkConf` in the Spark job k8s definition file, and adjust it to your actual path.  The path to the `metrics.properties` file should be set in your Dockerfile.

```
sparkConf:    
    "spark.metrics.conf": "/etc/metrics/conf/metrics.properties"
```

For reference, here's the rest of my `sparkConf`, for metric-related config.

```
sparkConf:
    "spark.metrics.conf": "/etc/metrics/conf/metrics.properties"  
    "spark.ui.prometheus.enabled": "true"
    "spark.kubernetes.driver.annotation.prometheus.io/scrape": "true"
    "spark.kubernetes.driver.annotation.prometheus.io/path": "/metrics/executors/prometheus/"
    "spark.kubernetes.driver.annotation.prometheus.io/port": "4040"
    "spark.sql.streaming.metricsEnabled": "true"
    "spark.metrics.appStatusSource.enabled": "true"
    "spark.kubernetes.driver.service.annotation.prometheus.io/scrape": "true"
    "spark.kubernetes.driver.service.annotation.prometheus.io/path": "/metrics/prometheus/"
    "spark.kubernetes.driver.service.annotation.prometheus.io/port": "4040"
```

Comment: So what should the contents of `metrics.properties` be?

Comment: @Jeremie Piotte - i've a similar requirement, and while it is working on my local m/c, i'm unable to make it work on GCP(Dataproc) + Prometheus on GKE .. here is the stackoverflow link -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73524235/monitoring-apache-spark-running-on-dataproc-metrics-from-prometheus-on-gke-2 .. any ideas on this ?